# How do I download files from a large dropbox folder?

Tags: linux, dropbox, wget

I want to download each/individual files from a large dropbox folder.

I usually download dropbox folder using `wget` option and following the link to the folder and append `?dl=1`.

However, now I have a folder that is large (more than 20GB) and this method does not work.

Is there any method using which I can list the individual files and download them?

Comment: From a programmatic standpoint, how are you doing this?  Are you just changing the URL in your browser previously?  What about the existing method *"does not work"* for you anymore?  What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: I'm using the wget command in terminal.

Comment: *What happens* when you use `wget`?  What error or message do you receive?  As it stands, this message is better suited for [superuser](http://www.superuser.com) if you're not trying to implement a programmatic method to download files.

Comment: I get this error: "ERROR 400: Bad Request". I have said this in the post, "However, now I have a folder that is large (more than 20GB) and this method does not work." which I remember dropbox does not allow larger than 20GB zip file.

What I think is is, there should be a programming way to list the files in a folder and downlaod them individually.

Comment: Can you show any effort or work you've done to script collecting all of the files, then separately downloading them one at a time?

Comment: Dropbox does offer an API you can use for listing and downloading files, among other operations: https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: Thanks everyone. I used an workaround. I heard about the dropbox API but do not want to learn a whole new api for this stuff (and it is not obvious from the api either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saved the dropbox folder from browser as an HMTL file and then used an HTML parser in python to produce an `sh` file that allowed me to download the whole folder. Here is the python script:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

d = pq(filename='dropbox_page.html')

K = d('.sl-link')
N = len(K)

shfile = open("fdn.sh", "w")

for i in range(N):
    link = K.eq(i).attr('href')
    Nl = len(link)
    link = link[:Nl-1] + '1'
    for j in range(Nl-1,-1,-1):
        if link[j] == '/':
            k = j;
            break

    shfile.write('wget ' + link +'\n')
    shfile.write('mv ' + link[k+1:] + ' ' + link[k+1:Nl-5] +'\n')

shfile.close()
```

Then in terminal

```
sh fdn.sh
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

First, since you need to access an existing shared folder, register a "Dropbox API" app with "Full Dropbox" access:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create

Then, get an access token for your account for your app. The easiest way is to use the "Generate" button on your app's page, where you'll be sent after you create the app. It's also accessible via the App Console.

Then, you can upload to a specified path via curl as shown in this example:

This uploads a file from the dropbox path path/to/file.txt to the local relative/path/to/file.txt in your PC, and returns the metadata for the downloaded file:

```
# Generated APPS(for Access tokens) @: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps
ACCESS_TOKEN=<-your-token-> && curl \
    -X POST  https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/path/to/file.txt\"}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --output relative/path/to/file.txt
```

<ACCESS_TOKEN> should be replaced with the OAuth 2 access token.

Comment: don't forget to tick permissions (files.content.read) in permissions tab if not ticked already, then save them with submit button at the bottom